# How can I use `psql` without installing via brew

Tags: postgresql, installation, psql, mac-os-x

I want to use the `psql` utility standalone, without installing postgress via brew or something (I have my reasons). I use psql version 9.5.3 on OS X, which was distributed with PostgressApp.

When I only distribute `psql`, I get the error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQsslInUse
...
Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

On most computers, `/usr/lib/libpq.5.5.dylib` is installed, but I use version 5.6. So then I tried distributing `libpq.5.6.dylib` in the same folder. This doesn't work, even when I set the `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it here: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/338

The problem was I used install_name_tool not 100% correctly, and I forgot to create aliases.